# Как создать EmailAdressAttribute только для почты Gmail

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, атрибуты

Для валидации контрола на ввод `email` использую `EmailAdressAttribute`. Можно как-то указать чтобы допустимым доменом был только `gmail.com`?

Comment: А вот этот пример не подойдёт? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @VladD, Не совсем понимаю как создать такой атрибут используя этот пример.

Comment: А не нужно создавать атрибут, можно же просто провалидировать как в примере.

Comment: @VladD, Можно просто, но хотелось понять, как создать такой атрибут.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно подсмотреть реализацию `EmailAddressAttribute` на [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs) и создать свой атрибут для валидации, немного подправив регулярное выражение:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class GmailAddressAttribute : DataTypeAttribute
{
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex(@"^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@gmail\.com$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

    public GmailAddressAttribute()
        : base(DataType.EmailAddress)
    {
        ErrorMessage = "The {0} field is not a valid e-mail address.";
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) {
            return true;
        }

        string valueAsString = value as string;
        return valueAsString != null && _regex.Match(valueAsString).Length > 0;
    }
}
```